# jQuery Ajax simple call

Tags: jquery

I'm trying a basic ajax call. So I'm hosting the following test php on a test server:
    http://voicebunny.comeze.com/index.php?numberOfWords=10
This web page is my own test that is already integrated to the VoiceBunny API http://voicebunny.com/developers.

Now I need to get the data printed by that web page in some other web page using jQuery.
As you can see the web page echo's some JSON. How can I get this JSON from another web page?

This is the code I have:

```
 $.ajax({

        'url' : 'http://voicebunny.comeze.com/index.php',
        'type' : 'GET',
        'data' : {
            'numberOfWords' : 10
        },
        'success' : function(data) {              
            alert('Data: '+data);
        },
        'error' : function(request,error)
        {
            alert("Request: "+JSON.stringify(request));
        }
    });
```

I have tried many other variations but I always get an error and never the JSON. Thank you

Comment: What's the error you're getting?

Comment: Unless you host your webpage and jquery on the same website, this is a cross domain call. Your website needs to explicitly allow cross domain calls and you need to enable it in the AJAX call as well (add `crossDomain: "true"`).

Comment: Hey the error variable only prints "error"

Comment: Hello TrueBlueAussie how do I enable it on the server? Do I need to contact the hosting service?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

please set the value of ***dataType*** property to ***json*** in the settings parameter of your ajax call and give it another try!

another point is you are using ajax call setup setting properties as string and it is wrong as  [reference site](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

```
$.ajax({

    url : 'http://voicebunny.comeze.com/index.php',
    type : 'GET',
    data : {
        'numberOfWords' : 10
    },
    dataType:'json',
    success : function(data) {              
        alert('Data: '+data);
    },
    error : function(request,error)
    {
        alert("Request: "+JSON.stringify(request));
    }
});
```

I hope this is helpful!

Comment: could you explain what the `(request,error)` variables are each for. How come you don't do anything with `error`?

Answer (score 21):

You could also make the ajax call more generic, reusable, so you can call it from different CRUD(create, read, update, delete) tasks for example and treat the success cases from those calls.

```
makePostCall = function (url, data) { // here the data and url are not hardcoded anymore
   var json_data = JSON.stringify(data);

    return $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: json_data,
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8"
    });
}

// and here a call example
makePostCall("index.php?action=READUSERS", {'city' : 'Tokio'})
    .success(function(data){
               // treat the READUSERS data returned
   })
    .fail(function(sender, message, details){
           alert("Sorry, something went wrong!");
  });
```

Comment: you mean cleaner

Comment: If we're suggesting English improvements as well as AJAX, the O.P. meant echos. No missing letters or ownership involved, means no apostrophe.
If I worked really hard I could bring such pedantry back on-topic. I doubt an admin would see it that way though.

Comment: or, "more clean." i suggest taking the high road and take correction better. don't "tawulk layaik thayusse" and not be able to handle a clean correction. in the name of human syntax and best practices. no harm in mentioning it. oh, thx, Umair for the code!