# How to make get and post API requests in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have a API code written in Ruby it call the API in the request in the loop as at a time we get max 50 results. But I want to make this API request in jQuery. And I have no idea how will I do this.

Here is my Ruby code:

```
totalsequence = []
    start = 0
    begin
      response = HTTParty.get("https://api.ontraport.com/1/objects?objectID=5&start=" + start.to_s,
        { 
          :headers => { 'Api-Appid' => '', 'Api-Key' => ''}
        })
        totalsequence = totalsequence + response['data']
        start += 50
    end until (response['data']).size == 0
    render json: JSON.pretty_generate(totalsequence)
```

So I want this code to be converted into jQuery.

Comment: I am not clear on what you are asking?

Comment: A quick google search would result in a ton of code samples, if it's only about converting the above code to jQuery.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery Ajax simple call](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19015897/jquery-ajax-simple-call)

Comment: How did this "do it for me" question get two upvotes? `:-(`

Answer (score 3):

In jQuery you can use [`jQuery.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "https://api.ontraport.com/1/objects?objectID=5&start=" + start.to_s,
    type: 'GET',
    headers: {
      'Api-Appid': '2_7861_X3YeBz0j1',
      'Api-Key': 'NXhYJvz2AsywN80'
    },
    data {
        'key1': 'value1',
        'key2': 'value2',
        ...
    },
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
      // handle success here via accessing data variable
      // returned from the server as response
    },
    error: function(error) {
      // handle error here via accessing error variable
    },
});
```

The `data` attribute specifies data to be sent to the server, which should be in key-value pairs.

See more about [jQuery Ajax Properties](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_ajax.asp).

Comment: I am getting this error `Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://api.ontraport.com/1/objects?objectID=5&start=50. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).`

Comment: Make sure you should enable CORS on the server where you are requesting...See this - http://enable-cors.org/server.html

Comment: @ElsieHamilton - If you find this answer correct and helpful then accept & upvote this answer as it motivates me to give answers to other questions like this and helps others to quickly find the correct answer!

Comment: Hi @SaumyaRastogi. Please note that the quote block (usually rendered in yellow and represented in Markdown with an angle bracket) is for quoted material (something someone said, material from a manual or a speech, etc). It is _not_ a general highlighter. I have downvoted for your edit warring and will be rolling back.

Comment: I notice [in this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41332354/472495) you have used a quote block, which might be for material from a manual (I cannot tell). If it is not, then please remove the quote block; if it is, please declare wHere it is from. It is perfectly acceptable to quote from a manual, just prefix it with a paragraph like `From the manual`, with an appropriate hyperlink to where that material can be found. This helps avoid the answer looking like plagiarism. Thanks!

Comment: Lastly, all of your answers contain [the hope that you have helped](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=user%3a1563528%20Hope%20this%20helps). Now, whenever _anyone_ posts an answer, they are probably hoping the same thing, but it can be taken as implied, and so is rather redundant. In general we prefer succinct posts here, it is generally best to omit this, and editors may remove it over time.

Comment: Hi Saumya, as above: `I have downvoted for your edit warring`. If you disagree with an edit then it is often a good idea to ping the editor to discuss. Please do that in future, thank you!

Comment: @halfer - Didn't get you, can you please tell me clearly, why are you just reviewing these silly things, I've never seen this before!

Comment: See [Why can people edit my posts?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing) I don't know how you've got to 4K without experiencing your posts being edited - it is very common here. Take it as a complement - it means that someone believes your material is worth improving `:-)`.

Comment: @halfer - The guide doesn't tell anywhere that you can dowvote the answers on these mistakes. I think editors are there to review & correct the answers instead of down-voting them. You could also tell me about this in comments instead of down voting. You're wrong here to downvote this answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131568/discussion-between-halfer-and-saumya-rastogi).

Answer (score 2):

You just try this.

**[Ajax post](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/)**

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: success,
  dataType: dataType
});
```

[**Ajax get**](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/)

```
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: success,
  dataType: dataType
});
```

Comment: I don't want it to go to ruby controller

Comment: If not a Rails controller, where then?  Also, shouldn't the URL in Ajax request say `/create`

Comment: just check this @ElsieHamilton

Comment: Is that okey @Sid

Comment: @ElsieHamilton are you check my answer?

Comment: @karthicknagarajan Yes I am checking

Comment: @ElsieHamilton Is that okay?