# Onchange of a input field changed by Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a input field `type="hidden"` which is changed by javascript itself.

When this field changes i want an event/function to be triggered.

Tried this:

```
$(".product_id").on("change paste keyup input", function(event){alert('1');});
$(".product_id").blur(function(event){alert('1');});
$(".product_id").keypress(function(event){alert('1');});
```

But it does not seem to work as the value is changed by other JavaScript file itself.

I cannot change or add to the existing JavaScript.
I cannot add anything to the input field.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use jQuery's [`trigger`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) method & [`change`](https://api.jquery.com/change/) event.

> Changes in value to hidden elements don't automatically fire the `.change()` event. So, as soon as you change the hidden inputs, you should tell jQuery to trigger it using `.trigger('change')` method.

You can do it like this:

```js
$(function() {
  $("#field").on('change', function(e) {
   alert('hidden field changed!');
  });
  
  $("#btn").on('click', function(e) {
   $("#field").val('hello!').trigger('change');
    console.log('Hidden Filed Value: ' + $('#field').val());
  });
  
  console.log('Hidden Filed Value: ' + $('#field').val());
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="field" type="hidden" name="name">
<button id="btn">
  Change Hidden Field Value
</button>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I am having a problem with this ..there is a selector field which leads change to this hidden input field so the only thing i have to trigger the change is this selector field but when i use the above method it triggers my change first and after that it triggers the selector change so i end up with the wrong value.

Comment: Can you specify on which event does your hidden fields changes, if you can give me your code in - jsfiddle link, I can help you with that!

Answer (score 1):

It's just a hack if you can't trigger `change` event from sources.

May not be a good solution with `setInterval()`. But helps in the cases where you can't trigger `change` event from sources which are changing the `hidden` `input` value.

```js
$("#input")[0].oninput = function(){
  $("#hidden").val($(this).val()); //setting hidden value
}
var oldVal = $("#hidden").val();
setInterval(function(){ //listening for changes
  var newVal = $("#hidden").val(); 
  if(newVal !== oldVal){
    console.log(newVal);
    oldVal = newVal;
  }
}, 1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="hidden" id="hidden">

<input type="text" id="input">
```

Answer (score -3):

```
var element = $(".product_id");
element.on("change", function(){
    alert('hey');
}).triggerHandler('change');
```

and we need to trigger it programmatically like:

```
$('.product_id').val('abcd').triggerHandler('change');
```

Comment: does no good to trigger event until after value is changed. No indication of that given in answer . Code only answers are of little value ... you should provide explanations