# Node.js + MySQL -> Make a db query from outside server.js?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

For example, I have a registration form and I also have a button for submitting the details, so once I click the button, I want them to be sent to the mysql database. Unfortunately, I only know how to do db queries on the server.js but how do I do it on any script? Below is the way that won't work

```
 $("button#submit").click(function () {
    var username = $('#usr').val();
    var password = $('#pwd').val();

    db.query("INSERT OR REPLACE INTO user_data (username, password) VALUES (" + username + "," + password + ")");
    //// something like this
 })
```

Comment: The code you have shown above seems to operate in a browser environment, *not* in Node.js.

Your browser's environment does not know about your Node.js code.

Comment: Your query above is **wide open** to SQL Injection attacks and errors. See: http://bobby-tables.com. Use parameterized queries.

Answer (score 1):

You can't run queries on a mySql database from the frontend. That would be a huge security issue. You'll have to send the values back to your backend and query the database from there, with the values.

Also make sure to use prepared statements. Your query is wide open to mysql injections.

[image]

You can run a prepared statement using node-mysql with `mysql.format()`:

```
var sql = "SELECT * FROM ?? WHERE ?? = ?";
var inserts = ['users', 'id', userId];
sql = mysql.format(sql, inserts);
```

Translated for your query, this would be

```
let query = "REPLACE INTO user_data (username, password) VALUES (?,?)";
let inserts = [username, password]; // however you obtain them in the backend
mysql.query(mysql.format(query, inserts));
```

Note that I changed `INSERT OR REPLACE` to [`REPLACE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replace.html), as it was a syntax error.

Comment: You'll need to make an ajax call from the frontend to a route on your server with the data. Here's a example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19015897/jquery-ajax-simple-call

Comment: I understand, but how do I tell the server.js what query to do. for example:  $('button#submit').click(function(){ /// send that prepared statement to the server } ); and then execute it on server?

Comment: Nothing(!!!!) related to mysql happens on the frontend. You send an ajax request with username and password as the data, then do everything mysql related on the backend

Comment: Thanks @T.J.Crowder I'll grab the comic - little bobby tables is such a nice guy :D

Comment: So what do I do after I am done with the ajax call?. Sorry if the question is stupid but I am still a bit new to this

Comment: @Caitiff If user registers successfully  you can redirect him to login page, if auto login is done then send him to dashboard or something like that. If any error occurs while registering then you can grab it and  show in the client side(some error message container)