# Login validation through JSON using JS

Tags: javascript, json

New at coding. So part of my assignment require me to validate login credentials through JSON.
user.json file would look something like this.. first is the email address then their password.

```
{
"mary@mary.com":"12345678",
"joseph@gmail.com":"293sfvdet"
}
```

my website will ask for the login and will go through JSON to validate the information. I am only allowed to use JSON, JS and HTML.I am definitely not familiar with JSON.

i would like to know how I could access my JSON file through JS and how i should go about using JSON for validation.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. SO is not a code writing service. We can only help you fix the code you've written.

Comment: I guess it’s homework!? Otherwise I‘d suggest not to store login credentials unsafe in an json-File.

Answer (score 0):

You may link your local json file in the page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="user.json"></script>
```

Then you can use it like:

```
var userdata = JSON.parse(user);
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all (although you are maybe aware of this) **this is not a secure way to implement a login at all** but I assume, since this is for your assignment, this isn't really relevant to you.
Instead of writing your user data into a seperate JSON-file, you could just declare a constant inside your JS code like so:

```
const users = {
  "mary@mary.com":"12345678",
  "joseph@gmail.com":"293sfvdet"
}
```

After that you could just validate the entered credentials against this.
You may want to read [this](https://www.w3schools.com/jS/js_objects.asp) to learn more about javascript objects.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to want to use Javascript to read the contents of the JSON file. ([jQuery can help with this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19015897/jquery-ajax-simple-call), if you're allowed to use a library, otherwise, [look into fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)).

Then, you'll take the returned object that will look something like: `response = { "mary@mary.com":"12345678", "joseph@gmail.com":"293sfvdet" }` and you'll check to see if the email/password entered matches any record in the json.

```
var enteredEmail = 'mary@mary.com';
var enteredPassword = '12345678';
if(response[enteredEmail] == enteredPassword){
    // login validated. 
}
```

As other users have pointed out, **storing user info in a JSON file like this is not a secure practice** - nor is it practical. However, if it's just an assignment, this should work.