# How to impelment each function in countdown code

Tags: javascript, jquery, each

My task is to display countdown from current date to date stored in mysql field. Im fetching the results with while loop with php. There is no problem with showing the results, but I need help with implement each function to my jQuery code.

```
<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var countDownDate = new Date("03.29.2019 18:00:00").getTime();

var x = setInterval(function() {

  var now = new Date().getTime();

  var distance = countDownDate - now;

  var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
  var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
  var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = hours + "ч "
  + minutes + "м " + seconds + "с ";

});
</script>
```

Comment: Your code seems fine, what are the other functions?

Comment: Also this contains no jQuery

Comment: Check your date format, var countdownDate = new Date("2019-03-29T18:00:00).getTime();

Comment: Is the question really about how to set up the ajax call? If so does this question help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19015897/jquery-ajax-simple-call