# Alert if click ok update 2 row from database else do nothing

Tags: javascript, php, sql

i have a problem, i have a script that when i click a button it update data on database, but also display an alert. what im trying to do is, if i click "OK" on the alert it must update or insert (if there is no data) new data (on row statuscomanda and statuscomandatapiterii = "EXPEDIAT"). if i click cancel do nothing

this is what i got, i got the connection to the database.

```
<script>
function loaded()
{
if (confirm('A fost livrata comanda?')) { 
// Save it!
} else {
// Do nothing!
}
window.setTimeout(CloseMe, 200);
}

function CloseMe() 
{
window.close();
}
</script>
```

i have tryed this:

```
<script>
function loaded()
{
if (confirm('A fost livrata comanda?')) <?php $sql = "UPDATE $table SET 
statuscomanda='expediat' statuscomandatapiterii='expediat' WHERE id=$id"; 
?> { 
// Save it!
} else {
// Do nothing!
}
window.setTimeout(CloseMe, 200);
}

function CloseMe() 
{
window.close();
}
</script>
```

i tought if i add this, it should do the job

if i click ok just update or add (if there is no data in the specific row) , the data updated should be "expediat" if i click cancel do nothing :)

EDITED!!

i have tried this ,

```
function confirmDelete() {
    if (confirm('Doresti sa schimbi in expediat?')) {
        //Make ajax call
        $.ajax({
            url: "test2.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: {id : 5},
            dataType: "html", 
            success: function() {
                alert("A fost schimbat in expediat");
            }
        });

    }
}
```

used external php file nammed test2.php , that file change the data into database, but still not working if i press the yes button

Answer (score 1):

First off PHP will always get executed before the page load, so in other words you can't call PHP from javascript functions.

That said you can call PHP routes from javascript functions using AJAX. Either that or you use javascript to submit a form to a php script.

Those are really your 2 options.

See this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19016091/6751133

Comment: This was going to be my answer, although I was going to add that the OP doesn't need to add an "else" unless it actually does something.

Comment: That is true, it's just more whitespace in your code if you do :P

Comment: IMO, useless code shouldn't be in the code. It adds to the clutter and potentially adds bugs, ie code smell. And it definitely adds to the mental overhead to "ignore this code", as I've seen commented in too many apps.

Comment: @PirjolNelu, there are a lot of AJAX tutorials out there. Keep trying different ones, since they usually are specific to one set of instances, and you need to find on that is close enough to your use case for it to work, and then for you to modify it so it works better.  Good luck!

Comment: @PirjolNelu, BTW, it's not as hard as it sounds. Once you do it a few times, it'll be pretty easy, and it's a good skill set to have for the future. You're likely to need it more than just this once, if you expect to do any halfway serious amount of coding.

Comment: Well until you come across an end user who disables javascript :)

Comment: i have edited my post, but still not working :( any ideea?