# Call java variables using for loop in java script function

Tags: javascript, java

I have a two variables fetching using for loop from database  named int id, int clust and call draw chart function of java script using these values. But it shows me nothing.
Where I am wrong??

```
                   <%
     int id =14;
       int clust = 2;
   
    %>
        <script>
 google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});


google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

  function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Id', 'Cluster No'],
     
for (var i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
data.push(<%=id%>,<%=clust%>);
   
}

    ]);
        var options = {
          title: 'Clusters Representation Using K-Means',
          hAxis: {title: 'Id', minValue: 0, maxValue: 4},
          vAxis: {title: 'Cluster No', minValue: 0, maxValue: 6},
          legend: 'none'
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.ScatterChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
    </script>
```

Comment: Can't work. By the time javascript is running, the code has been sent and the java servlet has closed

Comment: okk so what should I do to solve this issue??

Comment: Is this Java or JS? It looks mostly like JS, but you also have `int`s

Comment: @user edited. Both languages, taking java variables in java script

Comment: @ShaguftaJabeen Once you are running javascript the only way to interact with Java is to make an ajax call back to the (Java) server.

Comment: <%
           int kk[] ={5,4,3,2,1};
    %>
 function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Id', 'Cluster No'],
 // var i;
//for (i = 0; i < kk.length; i++) {
   [<%= kk[0] %>, <%= kk[0+1] %>],
    //    }
    ]);
    It works fine but when I remove comments its not. why??

Comment: @ControlAltDel,@flavio

Answer (score 1):

Your `data.push` call in the lopp will add to data JS array the values 23, 23 for 10 times.
I would suggest to save in some HTML input text component the data coming from DB, store those values in some JS variable, and then do your implementation using only JS variables

Comment: there are 100 or even thousand of records. how can I save them in input text component. Is there no any other useful method?? this is just example code taking 10 times.

Comment: You can perform an AJAX call, in the callback response coming from server you store the data you need and then you can call the JS method to fill the chart

Comment: how to do it?? could you tell me the code?? Actually I don't know about ajax calls.

Comment: You can have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19015897/jquery-ajax-simple-call and have a look to jQuery ajax call documentation and examples