# AJAX request posted to same page does not populate $_POST

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm working on a file, `form.php`, which needs to handle user input using an AJAX request so the page doesn't reload.  The user has 2 options - check or refresh data.  Below is the code.  The problem is, `$_POST` is not being populated.  When the Network tab in Firefox dev tools is examined, it shows the requests are happening.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="" method="post">
            <p>Select action for data -</p>
            <input type="radio" name="action" id="check" value="check">
            <label for="check">check</label>
            <br>
            <input type="radio" name="action" id="refresh" value="refresh">
            <label for="refresh">refresh</label>
            <br>
        </form>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $("input[type=radio][name='action']").change(function() {
                    var action = $("input[name='action']:checked").val();
                    executeAjax(action);
                });
            });

            function executeAjax(action) {
                return $.ajax({
                    method: "POST",
                    data: { action: action }
                })
                .done(function() {
                    console.log('success - ' + action + ' is the action');
                })
                .fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    console.log('ERROR');
                    console.log(jqXHR.status);
                    console.log(textStatus);
                    console.log(errorThrown);
                });
            }

        </script>
    </body>
</html>

<?php
echo '<hr>';
echo 'post - ' . json_encode($_POST) . '<br>';
$action = isset($_POST['action']) ? $_POST['action'] : 'no value';
echo $action;
// put logic here for what to do with with data based on value in $action'
?>
```

Request appears successful in Network tab:
[image]

Console shows success message from `.done` part of AJAX call:
[image]

So why doesn't `$_POST` contain they key `'action'` with whichever value the user selected?

Comment: You don't seem to even read what's returned from the server. What do you expect your code to do exactly?

Comment: How do I read what's returned from the server?  I thought it would just appear in `$_POST` and it could be `echo`ed to see what's there.  I added 2 lines of code near the bottom of the original code snippet to try and get the value the user submitted and echo it to the browser.  It displays "no value" in the browser no matter which radio button the user clicks.  What needs to be changed to get the value that's returned from the server?

Comment: Use `.done(function(data){ /* Do what you want with the data */ })`. You can also use ajax parameters instead. See example here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19016091/6512857

Comment: Hi @knot22, you are making an AJAX request and your code is right, but the only point is that you can not refresh the page through what you get from the AJAX response, in that case you should refresh it by refreshing the hole page not through the AJAX response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code your are not using response of the ajax method.

```
           done(function(reposne) {
                console.log('success - ' + action + ' is the action');
                console.log(response);
            })
```

Also you are using same form.php for ajax method. So your ajax response will print form html, And then your php $_POST related code.

Can you please put your php code at the top of the page, and put exit if form is posted. Otherwise print the form like

```
<?php
if(!empty($_POST)){
   // enter code here
   exit;
}
?>
<html> 
...
</html>
```